# What is this jQuery effect called

Tags: jquery

Can some one tell me what this jQuery effect is.

If you move the scroll bar the divs **move** across.

I can demonstrate it with this site. http://www.theblackeyeproject.co.uk/

Please can you assist.

Comment: It's just something that h-scrolls something when something else v-scrolls.

Comment: I think they call it annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Background Position is used:
http://keith-wood.name/backgroundPos.html

in combination with other scripts...

Answer (score 1):

Its Vertical Parallex effect

Here is an example/tut: http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/blog/code-tutorials/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/

and the demo thing: http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/